# Manage custom, machine specific configuration files in Salt

Tags: ansible, chef-infra, puppet, salt-stack, configuration-management

I am relatively new to Configuration Management tools for big infrastructure. The company will be using [Salt](http://saltstack.com/) for Linux and Windows, but I guess the question does not relate to specific tool.

The thing I don't get is, let's imagine we have 30 machines in cloud and couple of custom services installed for each of them. Versions can be different, depending on customer subscription. And each service has a config file that can have machine specific data. How you update config files for those services using Salt, or Puppet, Chef, Ansible kind of tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about Salt but in general in Configuration Management tools there is groups of hosts for several machines with the same configuration, templates and variables for customization for each machine 
for example you can specify variable `port=8888` for `host1` and `port=9999` for `host2`  but nginx-template will be something like this:

```
server {
        listen       {{port}};
       }
```

for the both servers.
The same idea with machine specific data example(ansible):

```
- name: start container with mon
  docker:
    name: test-mongo
    state: reloaded
    image: mongo
  when: master_ip == ansible_default_ipv4.address
```

where `master_ip` is my variable and `ansible_default_ipv4.address` is ip which ansible was connected to this host.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

With Chef you would use an Erb template for the config and interpolate based on node attributes in most cases. Those might be set directly on the node itself, or you could make a role per customer and set customer-specific attribute data in there.